# Check if Json Array contains objects in Logic App

Tags: arrays, json, conditional-statements, contains, azure-logic-apps

I am trying this out but I cant seem to get it to work.

In a Condition connector I'm doing this:

```
@contains(json(body('ParseCustomerDeltaXML')).newMembers[0], 'Member')
```

but i cant get it to work.

If it contains members it says true.

But if not i get an error:

> InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Condition' at line '1' and column '2706': 'The template language expression 'equals(json(body('ParseCustomerDeltaXML')).newMembers[0], null)' cannot be evaluated because array index '0' cannot be selected from empty array. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the error message, the array you are trying to reference the first item of is empty. You want to make use of the safe dereference operator `.?`

Suppose `newMembers` is an empty array. Then `newMembers[0]` would fail, but `newMembers?[0]` would succeed (and return `null`).

In the specific scenario you are describing, you may need to use a nested condition as well (i.e. first check if newMembers is non-empty, and then check for membership).

To check for emptiness you can use the `@empty()` expression.

Answer (score 0):

In my example I should check is element empty before fetching street data from element.

This works:

```
if(empty(body('Parse_JSON')?['results'][0]['addresses']), '', body('Parse_JSON')?['results'][0]['addresses'][0]['street'])
```

and this works too:

```
if(contains(['addresses'], ['addresses']?[0]), 'Do something', 'Or do this thing')
```

Hope that will help someone.